# Mobile Apps: React Native with Django REST

Tags: django, react-native

I'm looking to build a mobile application for app stores with React Native (for frontend) and a Django REST framework (for backend). I find that I learn quicker by following a start to end video/videos on how to integrate these parts together. I would appreciate any resources that could show me how to do this.
Going through the web, I found resources on how to build individual parts of frontend and backend but very little on a complete integration.

It doesn't need to be a complex app. It could be a simple example on how to retrieve GET and POST, JSON data from Django and showing that in React Native mobile app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) in your react native app. Also, use [ngork](https://ngrok.com/) for a secure tunnel on your local machine. If not, you might get an internal server error with `localhost:8000/url`.

**Example of POST and GET request:**

```
axios.get('http://74d021b9.ngrok.io/url').then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

axios.post('http://74d021b9.ngrok.io/url',{...data}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this repository on github its react native app with Django Api

https://github.com/rAnAaRsl/DsanoApp/blob/master/Url.js